# error handling in mulesoft in a flow referencing the another private flow

Tags: java, xml

How does the exception strategy works in mulesoft when we have a flow                       having its own exception strategy calling another flow with its exception strategy. What will happen if an exception occurs in the called flow.

Answer (score 1):

The called flow will throw the exception and the exception strategy of the called flow will be executed.
the calling flow wont throw an exception until its expecting something from the called flow and the called flow is not returning that.
Refer to this link [Mule_Exception](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Error+Handling)  for further detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception occurs in the called flow,The exception strategy of the called flow will get execute and control pass to calling flow to execute next message processor.

Regards,
Purnachandra